# What's the best way to allocate the variables with multiple combinations

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, scripting, initialization

I want to reduce the initialization of multiple combination variables.

My aim is to create a function and pass a function with variable. 
If I pass a variable x into function value(x); I should get output as "123". Similarly, if I pass a variable xy into function value(xy), then I should get output as "123456". Basically, I want to concatenate variables

Here is the javascript code as

```
   var x = "123";
   var y = "456";
   var z = "789";
   var a = "0-+";

   var xy = x + y;
   var yz = y + z;
   var zx = z + x;
   var xa = x + a;
   var ya = y + a;
   var za = z + a;
   var ax = a + x;
   var ay = a + y;
   var az = a + z;
   var xz = x + z;
   var yx = y + x;
   var zx = z + x;
   var zy = z + y;
   var xyz = x + y + z;
   var xyza = x + y + z + a;

   function value(input) {
         console.log(input);
   }
```

Sample execution as follows:

```
  value(x); //output: 123
  value(y); //output: 456
  value(xy); //output: 123456
  value(za); //output: 7890-+
```

In this case, there are lots of combination for the above variables i have defined to meet all possible combinations. I want to validate the user input from the above combination and also i dont want to write so many variables. Is there any possible easy solution ?
Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: What does "better" mean?

Comment: We have to write all combinations such as 4 variables and all other combinations. so, 4 x 4 = 16 combinations i have to define variables. So, I want to know if there are better ideas.

Comment: Please supply an actual example.  Your code does not seem to correlate with the question you're asking.

Comment: @Dave Please see the complete example with the output details. I want to get rid of these too many variables and I want to validate all possible combinations.

Comment: Still incredibly confusing.  Can you EXPLAIN the actual problem instead of giving an abstract list of variables that we're repeating through for some unknown reason?  Also, that isn't every combination.  What about vars `xya` or `azx`?

Comment: @Dave There is no usecase. I am learning javascript. Basically, I have 4 variables with some data. Now, I am passing any one of the four variables to a function. To further increase complexity, I tried to merge two variables such as xy, yz, etc.. so, this time, when I pass a variable with combination of other variables, output should be adding those two variables. I hope you got it now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would declare a global object to store the variables as keys:

```
var globals = {
   "x": "123",
   "y": "456",
   "z": "789"
};
```

Note that you can refer to your "variables" by `globals.x`, or `globals.y` (you can replace `globals` with a shorter keywork to reduce code of course).

It is a little extra effort to define the "variable names" with quotes.
However, now you get to use:

```
alert(Combinate("xz"));
// output: 123789
```

With a function like:

```
function Combinate(phrase) {
  result = "";
  for (var i = 0, len = phrase.length; i < len; i++) {
    result += globals[phrase[i]];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/77qjLo47/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use some form of iterating over an array or object.  As an example:

```
var x = "dave";
var y = "bill";
var z = "john";
var a = "suzan";
var people = [x,y,z,a];

for(i=0; i<people.length; i++) {
    for(x=0; x<people.length; x++) {
        value(people[i] + people[x]);
        for(y=0; y<people.length; y++) {
            value(people[i] + people[x] + people[y]);
            for(z=0; z<people.length; z++) {
                value(people[i] + people[x] + people[y] + people[z]);
            }
        }
    }
}

// not sure why you'd have a function to wrap console.log(), but...
function value(input) {
    console.log(input);
}
```

See [in action on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umzje34w/).

There are more elegant paths, but this should get you on the road to learning about JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. I am creating function ... so that If a user want to enter xy variable together. he should get both x value + y value together. eg. value(xy) should be davebill. value(yx) should be billdave. In this case, input is xy.

Comment: @GoldenWave It's sounding like you just want someone to write the code for you.  I've already gone beyond the scope of this site.  I would suggest trying some JS tutorials..etc to learn the language.